# Cambiar los atributos con cajas de texto

Tags: javascript

Hola quisiera saber como puedo cambiar los atributo de la imagen que puse,tengo una imagen, a la cual le quiero que la caja uno se le ponga el atributo a cambiar, y a la caja 2 el valor. Ejemplo. Caja1 = "backgroundcolor", y caja2="red" asi para que el usuario modifique a su antojo

```
function pushar2 ()
{
let div =   document.getElementById("imagen");
var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1");
var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2");
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Examen</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <h1>El examen</h1>
<input type="button" name="boton" id="boton" value="puchar" onclick="puchar()">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1" placeholder="atributos">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2" placeholder="valores">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" name="prueba" id="prueba" value="pushar2" onclick="pushar2()">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" name="prueba" id="prueba" value="info">

<br>
<br>
<div id="imagen">
    <p></p>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="funciones.js"></script>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta.

Comment: tengo una imagen, a la cual le quiero que la caja uno se le ponga el atributo a cambiar, y a la caja 2 el valor. Ejemplo. Caja1 = "backgroundcolor", y caja2="red" asi para que el usuario modifique a su antojo.

Comment: Se entiende un poco mejor, pero no queda claro que son tus *cajas*, si son elementos que existen ya en el HTML o elementos que creas de forma dinámica. El código que muestras no indica lo que hay en tu contexto, por ejemplo si hay algún contenido HTML, el cual sería bueno que también pongas en la pregunta. No entiendo por ejemplo por qué usas `createTextNode` o para qué lo usas ¿?

Comment: "cajas" se refiere a los textbox, como textbox del atributo y textbox del valor. En cuanto lo del createTextNode se me fue, olvidé por completo que estaba ahi.

Comment: Volví a editar la publicacion y el codigo, hasta el momento no sé como puedo realizar lo que quiero, solo tengo declaradas las variables.

Comment: ¿Eso es un ejercicio? Es algo muy raro lo que quieres hacer aquí, si lo dejas a la libertad del usuario y éste escribe `juanita` en vez de `background` ¿cómo lo vas a controlar? Pregunto solamente porque me parece raro eso que quieres hacer y quizá se pueda hacer de otro modo.

Comment: Pues es un ejercicio, nada mas importa el uso de nodos, mi duda es el como lo puedo resolver, no necesariamente que alguien lo haga, tal vez una sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar este código, el cual hará una validación de las propiedades y valores que se escriban.

Si son válidas las atribuirá al elemento, si no lo son, lanzará un `alert` (esa parte la puedes modificar).

Para la validación el código usa [`CSS.supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports), si no tiene importancia para los fines del ejercicio puedes quitar la validación, la cual ocurre aquí:

```
 if (CSS.supports(cssStyle)) {
    imageDiv.setAttribute('style', cssStyle);
  } else {
    alert("Escribiste un atributo o propiedad erróneas");
  }
```

en ese caso dejaría sólo:

```
imageDiv.setAttribute('style', cssStyle);
```

Te dejo una prueba funcionando, espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
function setCSS() {
  var propName = document.getElementById('caja1').value;
  var propValue = document.getElementById('caja2').value;
  var imageDiv = document.getElementById('imagen');
  var cssStyle = `${propName}: ${propValue}`;
  if (CSS.supports(cssStyle)) {
    imageDiv.setAttribute('style', cssStyle);
  } else {
    alert("Escribiste un atributo o propiedad erróneas");
  }
}

var punchar = setCSS;
var punchar2 = setCSS;
```

```html
<input type="button" name="boton" id="boton" value="puchar" onclick="punchar()" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1" placeholder="atributos">
<br>
<input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2" placeholder="valores">
<br>
<input type="button" name="prueba" id="prueba2" value="pushar2" onclick="punchar2()">
<br>
<input type="button" name="prueba" id="prueba" value="info">
<hr />
<div id="imagen">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```