# Cambiar propiedad CSS definida por el usuario con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Quiero que se aplique la propiedad de los input y que se vayan acumulando, por ejemplo si pone el borde azul y el fondo amarillo, que tenga un borde azul y un fondo amarillo.

***Al volver a poner una propiedad que ya esta definida se eliminará esa propiedad.***

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    let cambiar = document.querySelector("#b1");
    let propiedad=document.querySelector("#propiedad");
    let valor=document.querySelector("#valor");
    cambiar.addEventListener("click",function() {cambiarCSS(propiedad.value,valor.value)});
    
    function cambiarCSS() {
      /*???*/
    }   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS</title>
</head>

<body>
    Propiedad: <input type="text" id="propiedad" name="propiedad">
    Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor">
    <button id="b1">Cambiar css</button><br>
    <p id="parrafo">Cambiame</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. [Esto se parece mucho a tu requerimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/234064/29967), el código controla si la propiedad es válida en CSS mediante `CSS.supports`. Sólo tendrías que agregar la nueva propiedad en vez de cambiarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar los métodos [setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) y [removeProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty)

Si la propiedad ya existe en el objeto `parrafo.style` lo eliminas y si no existe lo añades.

Limitaciones: Si no pones propiedades generales (por ejemplo `border` con valor `1px solid blue`) tienes que tener en cuenta que te va a añadir más de una propiedad `CSS` (para ese ejemplo te pondría las `border-color`, `border-style`, etc.)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    let cambiar = document.querySelector("#b1");
    let propiedad=document.querySelector("#propiedad");
    let valor=document.querySelector("#valor");
    cambiar.addEventListener("click",function() {cambiarCSS(propiedad.value,valor.value)});
    
    function cambiarCSS(prop,val) {
      let parrafo = document.getElementById("parrafo");
      
      if(Object.values(parrafo.style).indexOf(prop)>-1){
        parrafo.style.removeProperty(prop);
      }

       parrafo.style.setProperty(prop, val);

    }   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS</title>
</head>

<body>
    Propiedad: <input type="text" id="propiedad" name="propiedad">
    Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor">
    <button id="b1">Cambiar css</button><br>
    <p id="parrafo">Cambiame</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cambiando _Object.values(parrafo.style).indexOf(prop)>-1_ por _parrafo.style[prop]!=""_ se consigue eliminar la propiedad pero la elimina siempre y no la sobrescribe en caso de que no sea igual.

Comment: eliminando el `else` y dejando solo `parrafo.style.setProperty(prop, val);`  es una opcion mas fiable ya que si existe elimina si no solo aplica. con el else evalua y ejecuta haciendo que se deba hacer 2 click en el button para aplicar la segunda vez una propiedad!